# ps cuts command, how to get full

Tags: command-line, ps

If I run the following command, the command line is cut:

```
user@host:~$ ps -eo pid,cmd,lstart
```

Output:

```
6382 /home/user/bin/pyt Sun Oct 22 18:51:39 2017
```

How to get the whole command (inclusive all arguments)?

Version: procps-ng version 3.3.5

Comment: what does mean your *whole command*?  try `ps -aux` ...

Comment: `man ps`. Your question suggests you want `ps elf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

swap columns:

```
ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd
```

Comment: `ps` man clarifies this:  "When specified last, this column will extend to the edge of the display". See `args` (alias `cmd`): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#STANDARD_FORMAT_SPECIFIERS